# Vue.js: Default data in component is always overridden with v-with

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a language selector view that includes a dropdown component. I want to set a default property (`isOpen`) in the dropdown component and then include computed data from the language selector, that is then displayed in the dropdown.

Yet I can't seem to find a way to define `isOpen` in the dropdown component without it being overriden by the new data from the language selector.

Here are the files:

language-selector.js

```
var model = require('model/language');
var uiDropdown = require('ui/dropdown');
var template = require('./index.html');

var vm = new Vue({
    template: template,
    components: {
        'ui-dropdown': uiDropdown
    },
    created: function() { self = this; },
    ready: init,
    data: function(){ return model; },
    computed: {
        dropdown: {
            get: function(){
                return {
                    options: (function(){
                        return model.options.map(function(option){
                            return { id: option.id, label: option.code }
                        })
                    }())
                ,   currentID: model.currentID
                ,   type: uiDropdown.opt.types.SMALL
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

language-selector template (index.html):

```
<div v-component="ui-dropdown" v-with="dropdown"></div>
```

dropdown.js (with `isOpen` defined in `data`. I also tried defining it both in the `created` and the `ready` hooks, yet it didn't work either):

```
var template = require('./index.html');

module.exports = {
    template: template,
    created: function() {
        self = this;
    },
    ready: init,
    methods: {
        onSelect: onSelect,
        onOpen: onOpen
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            isOpen: false,
            type: types.SMALL
        }
    },
    computed: {
        currentLabel: {
            get: function(){
                var selectedModel = filterSelected(self.$data, self.$data.currentID);
                return self.$data.options[self.$data.currentID].label;
            }
        }
    },
    opt: {
        types: types
    }
}
```

And finally the dropdown template (index.html):

```
<div class="dropdown {{ isOpen ? 'dropdown__open' : ''}}" v-class="type">
    <a v-on="click: onOpen" href="#" class="dropdown--label">
        {{ currentLabel }} {{ options.isOpen }}
        <span class="icon__dropdown"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown--list">
        <li v-repeat="option: options" class="{{ currentID == option.id ? 'dropdown--list__current' : '' }}">
            <a v-on="click: onSelect" href="{{ option.id }}">
                {{ option.label }}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

And here the output of the $data of the dropdown component (which lacks the `isOpen`):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the VueJS Guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Down_Individual_Properties):

> v-with can also be used with an argument in the form of `v-with="childProp: parentProp"`. This means passing down `parent[parentProp]` to the child as `child[childProp]`

Basically you're overriding *all* of the child component's data by using `v-with`. You should instead specify which properties to override using the second form of the directive.

Comment: Thank you, I came to this after a while. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a clean way to replace the child data with the parent data *only where the parent key is the same as the childs* and to keep the rest.

Comment: Yeah I think I agree with you there. I might suggest this as a feature on GitHub.